# React Hooks - useReducer: Wait for reducer to finish before triggering a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the component using `useReducer` Hooks:

```
const init = {
  statA: true,
  statB: true
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ActionA":
      return { ...state, statA: !state.statA };
    case "ActionB":
      return { ...state, statB: !state.statB };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, init);

  const clickMe = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "ActionA" });
    dispatch({ type: "ActionB" });
    console.log(state);
  }

  return(
      <button onClick={() => clickMe()}>Click Me</button>
  );
};
```

When the button is clicked, the state will be changed. But when I view the log, it prints the previous state, not the current updated state.

```
//On the first click
//Expected
{ statA: false, statB: false }
//Reality
{ statA: true, statB: true }

//On the second click
//Expected
{ statA: true, statB: true }
//Reality
{ statA: false, statB: false }
```

I know that with `setState`, I can use callback to work with updated state. But with `useReducer`, I don't know how to work with the updated state. Is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: hmm I know that when you `setState` the new state isn't reflected in the function.  what happens when you change out the `console.log(state)` from `clickMe` and show the state when the component is rendered? is the change reflected there?

Comment: it's how it should be: see, your reducer returns cloned state merged with additional data rather mutating same object. but variable `state` points onto old object. it will be linked to newer one on next render. so instead of fighting this please describe what do you need in the end so we can suggest better way to achieve that

Comment: Couldn't you just cause the side-effect inside of the reducer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`console.log(state)` is side effect. Side effects belong to `useEffect` hook:

```
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, init);

  useEffect(() => {
    // a condition may be added in case it shouldn't be executed every time
    console.log(state);
  }, [state]);

  const clickMe = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "ActionA" });
    dispatch({ type: "ActionB" });
  }
```

Comment: This is not a solution for my problem but it gives me an idea for a solution, and that solution works. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome. If you will have problems, consider asking a new question with your case explained in detail, there can be better ways to solve them.

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: @Jwan622 To wait for a reducer to finish inside useEffect.

Comment: @TríPhan You are logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) the state is re created but the callback passed as the click handler is not so it still has the old state available in it's closure.

Comment: @Jwan622 Waiting for reducer to finish is not an option because it is logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) the state is re created but the callback passed as the click handler is not so it still has the old state available in it's closure.