# why am i getting different outputs if use react hooks and class based components?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-state-management, react-state

```
const Home = props => {
  let [sta,steaa] = useState({h:80});
  const clickHandler = () => {
    console.log(sta.h);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      steaa({h:89});
      console.log(sta.h);
    },2000);
    steaa({h:89});
    steaa({h:150});
    console.log(sta.h);

    console.log("click handler in home.js");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home</h3>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

output:

80

80

click handler in home.js

80

```
class Home extends Component{
  state={
    h:80
  };
  clickHandler = () => {
    console.log(this.state.h);
    setTimeout(()=>{
     this.setState({h:89});
      console.log(this.state.h);

    },2000);
    this.setState({h:89});
    this.setState({h:150});
    console.log(this.state.h);

    console.log("click handler in home.js");
  };
 render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home</h3>
      <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
 }
};
```

output:

80

80

click handler in home.js

89

why am i getting different outputs if use react hooks and class based components?

As you can see the output is changing when I am using class based components instead of react hooks

why?????

Comment: `useState` is asynchronous, you will not immediately get your new state right before updating the state. You will get your new state after the component re-rendering. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55559530/8884948

Comment: use useEffect to display the value of h once it got changed.

Comment: why is it not happening in class based components??