# Using a callback with useReducer / Redux reducers

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I've been looking for a solution to "promisify" `useReducer` do something once I'm sure that the state has been changed as per my dispatched action. I found some promising stuff, such as this [feature request](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15344) and a few solutions similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559307/react-hooks-usereducer-wait-for-reducer-to-finish-before-triggering-a-functio) that's based on combining `useReducer` with `useEffect`. So instead of using a promise, I've tried to use a callback instead and I want to note here that this implementation works. But I'm unsure if there are any drawbacks to this.

**Note, the use case here isn't to call a function per every time the state changes, but rather the option to do something when the reducer finishes processing an action.

As per Redux rules, my reducer does not mutate state.

```
const emptyState: IState = {
  str: '',
  obj: {
    propA: 0,
    propB: 0,
  }
}

interface ReducerActions {
  type: 'changeStr' | 'changeObj';
  callback?: (newState: IState) => any;
}

const reducer = (state: IState, action: ReducerActions): IState => {
  let newState = {...state};
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'changeStr':
      newState.str = action.newStr;
      break;
    case 'changeObj':
      newState.obj = action.newObj;
      break;
  if (action.callback) {
    action.callback(newState);
  }
  return newState;
}
```

I did notice that this works in reverse of the traditional flow, where the callback or promise is executed *after* the state has changed, but should it matter when the callback is called using the value of the new state anyways?

And, are there any drawbacks or side-effects of using this method (whether here or in a Redux implementation)?

Comment: " but should it matter when the callback is called using the value of the new state anyways". Isn't that how it works originally? To answer your question, we might need some more information like what's your use case?

If you want to use a callback to be fired everytime that value is updated, why not use `useEffect`?

Comment: I've added a note to the question, which can hopefully clarify a bit more. I'm aware I can use useEffect, but that would trigger every time the state gets changed, not every time an action gets called. Basically, the use case would be calling an action, then doing something with the new state after the action is processed. I can be able to call changeStr in 2 different places, but one would have a callback, while the other would not. The callbacks do not have to be aware of what changed in the state.

Comment: To simplify down even further, I want to know if there are side effects of using the "newState" before it's actually set as the newState. Using my above implementation, callback(newState) gets called before the reducer actually returns the newState. The use case doesn't actually really matter since this implementation already does what I want it to do. Rather, I was to know if I'm correct in my implementation and if it follows React best practices (as I'm aware that this seems kind of a hack-y approach lol).

Comment: I can't seem to wrap my head around why would you need an action that does the state update and then a custom callback. Whenever you change your state its better to sync the changes via `useEffect`. Is performance something that you are concerned about when calling `useEffect`? You would have the latest state available in your `callback`, you can then *choose* to call it however way you want

Comment: Hm, let's put it this way (and there are definitely different ways to implement this, but I'm trying to make it relevant to this implementation), the action changeStr replaces the string of state.str with a new string, using 2 buttons, one makes it longer, the other shorter. If I use useEffect, I can of course check the new value of the string and get the length, but I would not be able to get the length of the previous string without storing the previous value. If I pass a callback to the action implemented in the buttons, I know which button makes it longer and which one makes it shorter.

Comment: Another thing is that if I use useEffect, I have to specifically check which value has changed and how it changed, which isn't performant since it's redundant if I know which value and how it changed already (when I call dispatch the action). If I use a callback, I don't have to check, I already know which dispatched action needs the newState and which doesn't.

Comment: I'm also aware that I get the latest state in the callback, which leads to my original question of is there any side effects of using that latest newState before it's actually set. The callback with the newState gets called before the reducer "officially" returns and sets the new state,

Comment: Um okay, with regards to your use case. What if you could use separate actions for both your buttons?  (increaseLength and decreaseLength) In that case, you would know exactly what happened. (Correct me If I wrong). Answering what may happen if you call your callback without officially returning the state, you would not exactly be synching.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229994/discussion-between-nerdragen-and-rohit-kashyap).

Comment: The problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559307/react-hooks-usereducer-wait-for-reducer-to-finish-before-triggering-a-functio) is caused by a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) the state is re created but the callback passed as the click handler is not so it still has the old state available in it's closure. I would not use your solution because if you pass a callback that has other local values in its closure they would be stale as well and could give you some unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

> the action changeStr replaces the string of state.str with a new string, using 2 buttons, one makes it longer, the other shorter. If I use useEffect, I can of course check the new value of the string and get the length, but I would not be able to get the length of the previous string without storing the previous value. If I pass a callback to the action implemented in the buttons, I know which button makes it longer and which one makes it shorter.

Still not sure what your needs are but if you need the **previous** and current value to perform some logic you can write a custom hook:

```js
const { useReducer, useState, useRef } = React;

const init = { value: 'A' };
const TOGGLE = 'TOGGLE';
const toggle = () => ({ type: TOGGLE });
const reducer = (state, { type }) => {
  //toggle state.value between A and B
  if (type === TOGGLE) {
    return { value: state.value === 'A' ? 'B' : 'A' };
  }
  return state;
};
const selectValue = (state) => state.value;
const NONE = {};
//custom hook to detect changes between renders
const useChange = (value, callback) => {
  const ref = useRef(NONE);
  if (ref.current !== value) {
    if (ref.current !== NONE) {
      callback(ref.current, value);
    }
    ref.current = value;
  }
};
const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, init);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const value = selectValue(state);
  useChange(value, (pref, current) =>
    setMessage(`value changed from ${pref} to ${current}`)
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(toggle())}>
        toggle
      </button>
      <div>{value}</div>
      <div>{message}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

Example of using thunk with useReducer:

```js
const { useReducer, useRef } = React;

const init = { value: 'A' };
const TOGGLE = 'TOGGLE';
const thunkToggle = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const value = getState().value;
  //you can do async dispatch
  setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch({ type: TOGGLE });
    console.log(
      `action dispatched value was ${value} is now ${
        getState().value
      }`
    );
  }, 10);
  console.log(`value is now (nothing dispatched) ${value}`);
};
const reducer = (state, { type }) => {
  console.log(`in reducer action type: ${type}`);
  //toggle state.value between A and B
  if (type === TOGGLE) {
    return { value: state.value === 'A' ? 'B' : 'A' };
  }
  return state;
};
const SET_STATE = Date.now();
//custom hook to detect changes between renders
const useThunkReducer = (reducer, initialState) => {
  const state = useRef(initialState);
  const thunkReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === SET_STATE) {
      return action.payload;
    }
    return reducer(state, action);
  };
  const [rState, dispatch] = useReducer(thunkReducer, init);
  const thunkDispatch = (action) => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(thunkDispatch, () => state.current);
    }
    state.current = thunkReducer(state.current, action);
    dispatch({ type: SET_STATE, payload: state.current });
  };
  return [rState, thunkDispatch];
};
const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useThunkReducer(reducer, init);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(thunkToggle())}>
        toggle
      </button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

For completion; here is an example using middleware so you can add several middleware functions and not only thunk:

```js
const { useRef, useState } = React;

const compose = (...fns) =>
  fns.reduce((result, fn) => (...args) =>
    fn(result(...args))
  );
const mw = () => (next) => (action) => next(action);
const createMiddleware = (...middlewareFunctions) => (
  store
) =>
  compose(
    ...middlewareFunctions
      .concat(mw)
      .reverse()
      .map((fn) => fn(store))
  );
const useMiddlewareReducer = (
  reducer,
  initialState,
  middleware = () => (b) => (c) => b(c)
) => {
  const stateContainer = useRef(initialState);
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const dispatch = (action) => {
    const next = (action) => {
      stateContainer.current = reducer(
        stateContainer.current,
        action
      );
      return setState(stateContainer.current);
    };
    const store = {
      dispatch,
      getState: () => stateContainer.current,
    };
    return middleware(store)(next)(action);
  };
  return [state, dispatch];
};

//middleware
const thunkMiddleWare = ({ getState, dispatch }) => (
  next
) => (action) =>
  typeof action === 'function'
    ? action(dispatch, getState)
    : next(action);
const logMiddleware = ({ getState }) => (next) => (
  action
) => {
  console.log('in log middleware', action, getState());
  Promise.resolve().then(() =>
    console.log('after action:', action.type, getState())
  );
  return next(action);
};

const init = { value: 'A' };
const TOGGLE = 'TOGGLE';
const thunkToggle = () => (dispatch) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch({ type: TOGGLE });
  }, 500);
};
const reducer = (state, { type }) => {
  console.log(`in reducer action type: ${type}`);
  //toggle state.value between A and B
  if (type === TOGGLE) {
    return { value: state.value === 'A' ? 'B' : 'A' };
  }
  return state;
};
const middleware = createMiddleware(
  thunkMiddleWare,
  logMiddleware
);
const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useMiddlewareReducer(
    reducer,
    init,
    middleware
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(thunkToggle())}>
        toggle
      </button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Nah, I'm aware of this flow (using a useEffect and useRef to get the previous value). Just to reiterate again, I wanted to trigger a callback depending on the action, not on the value changed - which after talking about it with @Rohit, is against the Redux rules as callbacks introduce side effects. Either way, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Nerdragen Sounds like that would be something you would implement with thunk if you use Redux, useReducer does not allow for middleware but you can implement thunk by wrapping useReducer with a custom hook (see updated answer).

Comment: It's fine, I'm aware that useReducers do not allow for middlware. As I mentioned above, this was more of a thought experiment than an actual implementation question; actually using Redux would have destroyed that purpose. I was just trying to test the logic test of my callback implementation using useReducer while following the Redux rules.

Comment: Also, I believe that your implementation is flawed as well. According to the Redux rules, reducers should be pure; using functions as an action will introduce side effects.

Comment: @Nerdragen The reducer is pure (except the console.log but that is to demonstrate how it works and can be removed), the `thunkDispatch` isn't pure because it has to run side effects if the action is a [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#why-do-i-need-this). That is why I suggested implementing what you want to do in a thunk action. Thunks can combine multiple actions and get current state at any time as well as dispatch multiple actions themselves even after async code execution.